# Make images appear randomly in a div every few seconds... How?

Tags: javascript, html, image

Simple question, i have this DIV right, 400 * 250 px. And i have this image, fooi.png. 
How can i make fooi.png randomly appear somewhere inside that div (and it doesn't remove the other images that already have been appeared) every 2 seconds?

Edit:

What i've got:

```
        function placeimage(){
            $('#div').append('<img src="fooi.png" alt="image" id="'. Math.floor(Math.random()*55) .'" onclick="doclick(this.id);">');
            setTimeout(placeimage, 2000);
        }

        placeimage();
```

Comment: You need to ask specific questions Show code you have tried. A blanket how do I do this is not how this site works please edit your question

Comment: @mcgrailm What do you mean with specific? I can't realy explain it better, i just want to spawn an <img> tag with fooi.png in it, somewhere inside that div.

Comment: show what you have tried or are trying to do and where you are having trouble.  A good starting point would be to use a timer

Comment: @mcgrailm I've edited my post with what i already got. Now i need to spawn the img tag at a random place in the div... How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write some css first

```
#div img {position: relative; float: left }
```

and javascript some how like this below

```
function placeimage(){
        var t = $('<img src="fooi.png" alt="image" id="' +  Math.floor(Math.random()*55)  + '" onclick="doclick(this.id);">');
        $('#div').append(t);
        t.css('left', Math.floor(Math.random()*(400 - t.width())));
        t.css('top', Math.floor(Math.random()*(250 - t.height())));
        setTimeout(placeimage, 2000);
    }

    placeimage();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`setInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.setInterval):

```
function placeimage(){
    $div = $('#div');
    $div.css('position','absolute');
    id = 'ranimg'+Math.floor(Math.random()*55);
    left = Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt($div.innerWidth()));
    top = Math.floor(Math.random()*parseInt($div.innerHeight()));
    $div.append('<img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/e1122386990776c6c39a08e9f5fe5648?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="image" id="'+id+'" onclick="doclick(this.id);" style="display: none; position: relative;">');
    $img = $('#'+id);
    $img.css('top',left+'px');
    $img.css('left',top+'px');
    $img.show();
    setInterval(function(){placeimage();}, 15000);
}

placeimage();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/HfLZ4/

Comment: Okay, that also works to create a timeout, but i still want to get my image at a random spot inside the div!?! And that answer doesn't realy help...

Comment: @Thew - Yes, I figured that out once I went to make a demo. See edit and link. Note, I used my own gravatar and 15 seconds in the demo.